# Weight regression training data for libsvm

Tags: regression, libsvm

i am using libsvm to create a regression model (surface fitting). Is there also a way to give the training samples a weight? E.g. data that are in a certain spot are more of interest than others. So far the only way I found is to filter samples out before training but thats not quite what I want.

I know there is an option -w / -wi but that just seems to work for classification.

Comment: i am interested in the same question